# pleaaaaase HELP !!!! 

Tags: iphone, yahoo

i need to find out if i can take away the scribbles on a screenshot ? someone sent me a screenshot but scribbled out some words and i want to figure out how i can somehow see it. please help

Answer (score 6):

The blacked out part or scribbles on the image were rasterized and became a part of the picture when the screenshot was taken. So there is no way to remove the scribbles on top of the image as they are part of the image.